What is the required salinity for sauerkraut
I was thinking of making my own sauerkraut lately, so I have been watching some YouTube videos on the topic.
What stuck me as weird was that all videos gave an estimation on the amount of salt (in grams) to use based on the weight of the cabbage. Perhaps this method provides a good estimation that sets the salinity above the risk threshold (since a large portion of the cabbage weight is the water), but I would expect that the precise measurement should be dependent on the amount of water and salt type, and that the best thing to do would be to use a salinometer.
So, my questions are:

Am I missing something? Could it be that, by only measuring the water salinity, the cabbage could take-in some of the salt or let-out extra water and make the water salinity lower than what was the initial goal?
If that is not the case, and using a salinometer on the cabbage juice (and any water I might decide to add) would be a nice idea, what is the proper salinity level to go for? A related answer here would indicate to me something around 5% to inhibit growth and then let the future acidity move things forward, but I might be missing something because 5% sounds a bit too much (if I am calculating things correctly, other people seem to use something around 1.7%).


Wait, what exactly would you want to measure with the salinometer? Most of the water is in the cabbage at the beginning, before the salt and fermentation pull it out. Salinometers likely don't work well on cabbage.

@TooTea Some people mix the cabbage with salt and let the salt extract the water from the cabbage, so that they have don't have to add water themselves. I guess the alternative would be to add water yourself and not bother with the water that exists inside the cabbage already. In any case, you will end up having some water/juice at some point of the process, which would be what I was planning to use for salination measurement. I guess that the first method also releases some sugars from the cabbage that would affect the correct measurement, so that might be a problem worth considering.

@TooTea But even with the released sugars taken into account, perhaps it would be better to work based on the weight of water/juice released by the cabbage, instead of the total cabbage weight?

IMHO you're overthinking it way too much. Cabbage is >90% water, the variation won't be significant. The common recipe in around here (Central Europe) is "around 2% salt" by weight, again nothing extremely precise. And 1g of NaCl is 1g of NaCl. Never had I seen a case where you'd need to be adding water.

Largely a duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/63067/34242 and if the cabbage is fresh enough, there should be NO water added. So, salt per weight of cabbage is actually quite definitive. Than there's the minor issue that "a salinometer" is not a standard kitchen tool. Accepted values range from Stephie's German source low of 7.5g/kg to most US sources claiming 20-30g/kg - my own experience would put 30g/kg as too much. Adding water is only needed if the cabbage is dried out whe you shred and salt it.

@Ecnerwal I guess this link answers the question, assuming we consider that everything should be based on the cabbage weight. Perhaps I am overthinking it, as Dann says. On the other hand, someone might want to use something different than cabbage, and then the question kinda returns to hunt us... It feels weird that there is no standard way of selecting the salinity for all kinds of fermented foods. It feels to me like having to deal with 100 different recipes, while the underlying chemistry and biology is totally the same.
