Is my sauerkraut fermenting safely?
I put up a batch of sauerkraut using red cabbage. I’m concerned because I didn’t see any bubbling at first. Previous batches began bubbling almost immediately, and a lot.
This batch seemed to be doing nothing for a couple of days. It’s in a 1 gallon glass jar with an air lock, in a dark cupboard.
After two or three days I checked it and it was overflowing out the air lock (I didn’t leave much space). Does this indicate good fermentation or could Clostridium botulinum do that?
After two weeks it’s still red. Does that indicate that it’s acidic enough to prevent Clostridium botulinum growth?
Initially I wasn’t getting enough juice from the raw cabbage so I added salt water.
For flavoring I used juniper berries, black pepper, cardamom, garlic powder, a little home-made habanero pepper sauce, and a little bit of pickle juice for the dill flavor. I don’t know if the acidity of the pickle juice affected fermentation.

How much salt did you use in your brine?

@Brōtsyorfuzthrāx something just below the human LD50.  Clare learned cooking from Bender.

Some visual references for red cabbage sauerkraut here. Also for correct salt ratio, which you don't seem to have given any data for, despite attempts at humor in the comments by others. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/63075/34242 It should be getting pinker rather than remaining dark red.

Hi Clare and welcome to Seasoned Advice!
Some fermentations start quickly, whilst others take a little longer. It varies depending on what you're fermenting, and when and where you're fermenting it. This is part of the reason salt is used in fermentation. The salt helps keep various salt-intolerant organisms at bay until the salt-tolerant lactobacteria can take over and become the dominate organism in the environment.
The lactobacteria release carbon dioxide gas as they digest the sugars in the food. Then they ahem fart out bubbles of CO2, which creates a blanket of heavier than air, gas on the surface of the ferment. This is what displaces and forces the air / oxygen out of the airlock and it's also the reason why people shouldn't constantly be opening the lid / airlock and stirring their ferments.
An active ferment can mean that the brine makes its way into and out of the airlock. In such cases you should remove the airlock, and cover the ferment as you resterilise and refill the airlock. Clostridium botulinum can also create gas as it grows, but whether it creates enough gas to make sauerkraut overflow in just three days is kind of beside the point.
The real issue here is that no one can give you a definitive answer to whether the overflow was caused by fermentation or something else. Given the time frame involved and the ingredients used, I would go as far as saying that it sounds like fermentation is the likely suspect (I've had the same happen a few times in the past) but the only way you'll get an informed, reliable answer is to test the pH of your fermentation. At the very least, you could use some litmus test paper specifically for low pH but the colour of what is being tested can make test strips unreliable.
I'd say you're far better off getting a cheap electronic pH tester, which can be had for less than $10, and assuming you verify their accuracy, should give you a reliable way of telling whether your ferments are safe. Cheap pH testers often have limited lifespans though, as their non-replacable bulbs can get old or dry out. So personally, I opted for a more expensive but much longer lasting and more accurate Apera PH60, which can have its bulb replaced.

After two weeks it’s still red. Does that indicate that it’s acidic
enough to prevent Clostridium botulinum growth?

It could indicate that it's acidic but again, it doesn't guarantee that it is acidic, or acidic enough to be safe.

Initially I wasn’t getting enough juice from the raw cabbage so I
added salt water.

On the subject of salt... always make sure you calculate and measure your salt percentage properly. As I said at the start of the post, salt is there for more than just taste but a lot of new fermenters just eyeball quantities or they use unreliable, volumetric measurements. You should also try to use salt that is free of any additives such as anti-caking agents as they can inhibit fermentation.

For flavoring I used juniper berries, black pepper, cardamom, garlic powder, a little home-made habanero pepper sauce, and a little bit of pickle juice for the dill flavor. I don’t know if the acidity of the pickle juice affected fermentation.

The recipe sounds nice! Without knowing the quantity and acidity of the pickle juice though, it's not possible to say whether it inhibited the fermentation in a significant way.

The cabbage juice being red does indicate that the mix is acidic.  Whether it's acidic enough can be hard to tell just with red cabbage, but it does get darker as the acid gets stronger. Botulism doesn't produce acid, so if it's getting steadily darker that's a good sign.  If it turns purple, blue, green, or yellow then something is definitely going wrong.  Note that the simplest way to avoid botulism in sauerkraut is to not seal it air tight until after the bubbles get going.  It doesn't really need to be sealed at all, but sealing does reduce evaporation.

@Perkins "Note that the simplest way to avoid botulism in sauerkraut is to not seal it air tight until after the bubbles get going." Could you provide a citation for that please? It doesn't seam to make sense to me... I'm happy to be proven wrong though.

Botulism can only grow in an oxygen-free environment.  Once the lactobacillus gets going, then the acidity level will suppress botulism whether there's oxygen or not.  You do still want to keep the dust out since some molds and yeasts can adapt to the high salt and acid levels given enough time.  Air tight does suppress a lot of the bad things other than botulism.  It will also make yeast produce alcohol instead of vinegar. The lactobacillus doesn't care. Traditional sauerkraut crocks don't seal air tight, they just have a lid and a weight to keep things submerged.

The reason I asked for a citation is that I would like to know whether sealing the container actually increases the chances of C. Bot growing. An unsealed container is more likely to have the CO2 in its head space disturbed, and is therefore more likely to have a higher amount of oxygen present. But I would have thought that would only apply, in a significant way at least, to the head space and not under the water line where the C. Bot may be able to grow. I'd also argue that the advantages in using an airlock outweigh the drawbacks.

I also just wanted to point out that some traditional sauerkraut crocks, specifically the ones with a lid that sits in a water filled channel around the rim, do seal air tight... but the lack of the use of air locks in traditional fermentation may be the results of a lack of access to the cheap, high quality air locks we have today, rather than choice. Having said that though, I do concede that the use of an airlock is not essential but like proper sterilisation procedures, it's simply a way of increasing the probability that the fermentation will be successful and have a desirable outcome.

I don't know of any studies specific to sauerkraut, but you'll find a lot of warnings in the home canning section about vacuum sealing without proper sterilization growing botulism whereas leaving the same thing unsealed does not.  If the oxygen increase only affected the headspace then there'd be no need for airlocks.  An air-tight seal though suppresses a big swath of the things you don't want growing in it other than botulism, and enough salt will suppress the botulism enough for the lactobacillus to thoroughly outcompete it. So sealing is better unless you doubt the salt.

Here's a good way to explain the headspace:  The oxygen exchange rate has to do with surface area.  That's why if you take a lot of common fishbowl designs and fill them to the brim, your fish will suffocate, but if you don't fill them past the widest point, then everybody's fine. And that's why alcohol fermenting jug designs tend to have narrow necks, even though that makes cleaning them far harder.  And why they need to be filled full or you're far more likely to get vinegar.  The airlocks everybody uses narrow the gas-exchange area even further while still preventing pressure buildup.

For pickling you need a particular amount of salt in the saline solution for the food not to spoil. The standard is 6% salt by volume for meat and 8% for vegetables. This means you need a scale to weigh the salt. Different brands of salt vary widely regarding the volume of the salt. It would be best if you weighed the salt.
8% salt solution means 80 grams of salt per litre of brine. If you consider a gallon to be 5 liters then that means 400 grams of salt. Seeing as an ounce is 30 grams that means a 5-liter gallon amount of brine needs 13.33 ounces of salt.
If you consider a gallon as 4 litres then the amount of salt is 320 grams or 10,66 ounces of salt. Do use finely-grained salt, not coarse or flakey. The finer salt mixes best with the water.
If at all possible try to use a fine salt free of mineral additives and especially free of anti-caking agents. Anti-caking agent has a way of producing sediment at the bottom of your brine. As pure a fine sodium chloride as you can source.
The mineral-rich salt common in certain types of finishing salt has a habit of just putting some off-flavours into brines. Won't kill you, just not quite what you want

I think there are several issues with your answer. First of all, pickling and fermentation are not the same thing but perhaps that was a typo? Also an 8% brine solution for fermentation is very high. Speaking of using brine... Most traditional sauerkraut recipes use just the moisture released from the cabbage itself. With maybe a small amount of supplemental brine in the event that the cabbage doesn't release enough liquid to be fully submerged. So I think that give such large quantities as examples is not the best. And finally, your answer doesn't actually address the question being asked.

8% is very high. :) You wouldn't have to worry about the vegetables going bad any time soon, though. But they probably wouldn't ever ferment. Salty permacabbage. Might be good in soups.

@Brōtsyorfuzthrāx  I did about 8-9% once with cucumbers and yeah, perfectly good way to preserve them.  They stayed nice and crisp even.  And the flavors from the onions, dill, and peppers mixed in nicely, but they didn't get the slightest bit sour, even after a year.  Also, whatever dish you put them in, leave out the salt.  There will be more than enough salt...

@Perkins Great to know. I wonder if that works with tomatoes and other berries that I typically wouldn't want to ferment, but might like to keep something like fresh.

@Brōtsyorfuzthrāx Technically the answer is yes...  Most people don't particularly like super salty fruit though...  And whereas vegetables can be soaked to remove the excess salt before use, fruit's higher water content makes me suspect that wouldn't be effective.  Immersing fruits in honey or other, saturated sugar solutions is more likely to have pleasant results I would think.
